# Mixing inline attributes with an attribute object

Tags: jquery

I should get 3 images here but I get 2.  The last one fails:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    var img = $('<img src="icon.next.gif" url="/" />');
    $("body").append(img);
    img = $('<img />', { src: "icon.next.gif", url: "/" });
    $("body").append(img);
    var img = $('<img src="icon.next.gif" />', { url: "/" });
    $("body").append(img);
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I could swear I've mixed these before but now it seems like the second parameter replaces all tags.  I really need it to add because I've got a string generated (which comes with inline attributes) and I need to add to it.

Here's [[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2qSz/)] for anyone who'd like to play with it.

Using IE9 and it breaks with:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support
>   property or method
>   'createDocumentFragment' 
>   jquery-1.5.1.js, line 5450 character 3

Answer (score 1):

First, use `$(document).ready(function(){` or the shorthand `$(function(){`

Secondly, remove the url attribute from the third img and add the slash before the image src:

```
var img = $('<img src="icon.next.gif" url="/" />');
$("body").append(img);
img = $('<img />', { src: "icon.next.gif", url: "/" });
$("body").append(img);
img = $('<img src="/icon.next.gif" />');
$("body").append(img);
```

As long as you're pulling from a CDN, you should always try to grab the latest version of jQuery before posting a debug question, as the issue may have been resolved in jQuery itself.

You're using 1.5.1.  jQuery is on 1.6.2 now, fyi.

http://jsfiddle.net/x2qSz/2/

Comment: you're absolutely right.  I copied that from my project.  things move quickly.  anyway, 1.6.2 works!

Comment: I spoke too soon (just as well that SO wouldn't let me accept the answer yet).  it works insofar as it no longer breaks but now it just ignores my url for the last line.  no good.

Comment: Well url isn't even a valid img attribute. <img src="/icon.next.gif" /> will tell the browser to fetch the image relative to the webroot.

Comment: I know url isn't a valid attribute.  I use element attributes to keep useful information... change it to a valid attribute and it still fails: http://jsfiddle.net/x2qSz/3/

Comment: out of curiosity, what's wrong with $().ready()?  it has always worked for me

Comment: so it does... curiously, it doesn't explain why